# Is there any limit when using notify_workers method in boto mturk

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, mechanicalturk

I came across this file: http://jessechandler.com/uploads/2/8/0/5/2805897/emailing-workers-mueller-chandler1.pdf, inside which it mentions 'you can send up to 100 workerids at a time' when using `boto`. It doesn't give a reason for this.

Can someone confirm if this is a restriction of `boto` or even Amazon MTurk API itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a limit of the MTurk API.  See the [MTurk API reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_NotifyWorkersOperation.html) for details.

Comment: You can get around it though by just sending multiple requests. All email still gets delivered.